# Is there a way to get aKML data into a feature class?

Tags: arcpy, kml, feature-class

I have a couple of KML files and I need to use ArcPy to insert these KMLs into a feature class in the SDE. I’m new to ArcPy so I’m looking for advice on how to approach this. I already have a feature class but I need to get data from the KML file into it. The conversion tool KML to layer won’t put my data into my existing feature class.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a single step. As the KML to Layer tool creates a file geodatabase with one or more feature classes and a layer file, you'll need to then append the results to an existing feature class.

- Step 1: **[KML To Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/kml-to-layer.htm)**
- Step 2: **[Append](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm)**

Of course, you may need to check that the schema of the KML to Layer output matches the feature class you're appending to.